# Try with multiple Resource in Java

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I am new in `Java8`, and I want to know if, for the `AutoCloseable` resource, I have to add a `try` for each `resource`, or it will work with the code above

```
try (Connection conn = getConnection();) {

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rset.next()) {
                TelefonicaDataVO vo = new TelefonicaDataVO();
                vo.setTelefonicaDataId(rset.getString("Telefonica_PSD_ID"));
                vo.setReceptionDate(nvl(rset.getTimestamp("CREATION_DATE")));
                vo.setMessage(nvl(rset.getString("MESSAGE")));
                ret.add(vo);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try with resources can be used with multiple resources by declaring them all in the **`try`** block and this feature introduced in **java 7** not in **java 8** If you have multiple you can give like below

```
try (
        java.util.zip.ZipFile zf =
             new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFileName);
        java.io.BufferedWriter writer = 
            java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset)
    ) {
        // Enumerate each entry
        for (java.util.Enumeration entries =
                                zf.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();) {
            // Get the entry name and write it to the output file
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String zipEntryName =
                 ((java.util.zip.ZipEntry)entries.nextElement()).getName() +
                 newLine;
            writer.write(zipEntryName, 0, zipEntryName.length());
        }
    }
```

In this example, the `try-with-resources` statement contains two declarations that are separated by a semicolon: **ZipFile** and **BufferedWriter**. When the block of code that directly follows it terminates, either normally or because of an exception, the close methods of the BufferedWriter and ZipFile objects are automatically called in this order. **Note that the close methods of resources are called in the opposite order of their creation.**.

Please see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more info