# Is there a need to close resource if we use try-with-resource

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I am using try-with-resource block in my code, wondering is there a need to close the resource at the end of the method or not needed?

```
try (S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()));
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("output.txt")))){
  String line;

  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    bw.write(line);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: You also don’t need `bw.flush()`.  Closing the BufferedWriter (whether automatically or manually) will flush it.

Comment: No, there is no need for a `finally` block that closes the resources. See the answer below given by @ZhaoGang. I think you have to open a bracket behind the `try`-with resource.

Comment: Which resource? The `object` (really bad name, as it doesnt tell us much about the object) ... or the reader/writer you use inside the body?

Comment: @GhostCat they are not used in the body..

Comment: @ZhaoGang So opening and writing to a Writer in the body isn't using a resource?!

Comment: @GhostCat They are among the multiple resources

Comment: The encoding for reading and writing is the current platform encoding, so non-portable. And ` Files.newBufferedWriter` or even `Files.copy` save on typing.

Comment: By saying they are not used in the body.. in my previous comment what I really want to say is they are not defined in the body but the try-with-resource clause, together with the s3object. Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to **close** resources that you defined in the try clause. But, given your example, you also have this in the **body** of the try:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("output.txt"))))
```

and your code is **not**closing that resource. And that is wrong (and keeping file system handles open is most likely a real resource leak).

In other words: you probably want to add `bw` to your try-with-resources clause, so it sits along with the definition of `S3Object object` ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175526/try-with-multiple-resource-in-java) for an example ).

Comment: BufferedWriter is in try only clause only.

Comment: can you please give me some reference/code how to I can close more then one resource if I use try-with-resource, thanks

Comment: `try (S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()));
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/tmp/output.txt")))) {` sorry but I am still confused  s3, br and bw are in try clause only.

Comment: It goes like try ( clause ) { body } catch ... so, yes, you move the definition of all resources you want to be closed automatically from the "body" to the "clause" part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185165/discussion-between-jay-and-ghostcat).

Answer (score 12):

No.

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

And if you are using a java 6 or older:

> Prior to Java SE 7, you can use a finally block to ensure that a resource is closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly.

**Update:**

> You may declare one or more resources in a try-with-resources statement.

as you have used in your code.

Answer (score 4):

No, You don't. Let's take a look at an example of a `try-catch-finally` and `try-with-resource`

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

This is your regular `try-catch-finally` in this you are closing the scanner in the `finally` block. Now lets take a look at `try-with-resource`

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

You don't need to close the `scanner` here since it closes it self after the `try` block has done executing. For more ref visit this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources)