# Open connection in try-with-resources - second resource depend on first

Tags: java

I would like to use try-with-resources. I have two resources, where second depend on first. After initialize first, I need to execute method on first resources. Next I can initialize second resource. What can I do it?

```
try (First first = resource.get());
     --Here I need run method: first.connect(...);
     Second second = first.get())
     {
      ...
     }
```

Comment: Hope this will give an idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175526/try-with-multiple-resource-in-java/47175609

Comment: Use a second try-with-resources inside the try block of the first try-with-resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest try-with-resources, just like you can with normal try-blocks:

```
try (First first = resource.get()) {
    first.connect(...);
    try (Second second = first.get()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have: 
`try (First first = resource.get()) {
    first.connect(...);
    try (Second second = first.get()) {
        // ...
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){..}` 

When the second throw Exception, the first try-catch catch this exception?

Comment: @user11149927 of course, why do you think it wouldn't?! It is the first catch block that can handle the exception.