# Java try-with-resources multiple resources

Tags: java

I have a question about using try-with-resources with already-existing resources, a feature added to Java 9 as defined in [JEP 213](https://openjdk.org/jeps/213).

Let's take one of the examples I found online:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("testRead.txt"));
final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("testWrite.txt"));
try (scanner;writer) { 
    // omitted
}
```

to my understanding, if an exception is thrown within the try block the `scanner` and `writer` streams will be closed implicitly without our intervention.

But what happens if an exception is thrown at `new PrintWriter(new File("testWrite.txt"));`, won't the first stream remain open then?

Comment: I don't think it does, sorry. My question is relative to the new "effectively final" feature introduced in java 9 - JEP 213

Comment: @CollinD No, this Question is not a duplicate of [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47175526/642706). This Question refers to the newer feature of defining a resource *before* the `try`. This newer feature is not at issue in the other Question.

Comment: @IDK your question doesn't mention Java 9 nor JEP 213. This seems like a crucial detail

Answer (score 2):

Just put it inside the `try` statement:

```java
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("testRead.txt"));
     final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("testWrite.txt"))) { 
    // omitted
}
```

It does the right thing then.

## UPDATE #1

The specification says what happens if one of the initializers fails and throws an exception. This is from [*14.20.3. try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> Resources are initialized in left-to-right order. If a resource fails to initialize (that is, its initializer expression throws an exception), then all resources initialized so far by the try-with-resources statement are closed. If all resources initialize successfully, the try block executes as normal and then all non-null resources of the try-with-resources statement are closed.

Comment: yeah ok, but the example in my question is like the new feature from java 9:  

As of Java 9 and as part of JEP 213, we can now use final or even effectively final variables inside a try-with-resources block:

Comment: btw, are we sure that if the `writer` initialization fails in there, both resources get closed? I mean are we effectively inside the try block there?

Comment: @IDK Yes, see the citation that I added.